# How to reformat time in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

So I've broken this down to its simplest components and I'm still stuck. I've never dealt with dates and times in PHP before. I'm using ACF to set date and time for a webinar landing page template. I need the date to only print if it's in the future.

The initial time is coming in using g:i a format from ACF. The date is coming in as F j, Y.

```
$webinar_date = get_field(‘webinar_date’);
$webinar_time = get_field(‘webinar_time’);
$old_datetime = strtotime(‘$webinar_date $webinar_time’);
$new_datetime = date(‘Y-m-d H:i:s’, $old_datetime);

$now = date(‘Y-m-d H:i:s’);

if($new_datetime >= $now) {
echo get_field(‘webinar_date’);
echo get_field(‘webinar_time’);

}
```

It was working fine when I was using the below code to just compare date, so I think something with my time formatting is off.

```
$webinar_date = get_field(‘webinar_date’);
$today = date(‘Y-m-d’);

$old_date = strtotime($webinar_date);
$new_date = date(‘Y-m-d’ , $old_date);

if($new_date >= $today) {
echo get_field(‘webinar_date’)

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: I don't think so. It seems like exactly what I'm doing with mine, it just isn't working. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this one set date_default_set to your country GMT
`<?php  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Colombo");  $time = date('H:i:s',time()); ?>`